# access object method in a view within a loop php7

Tags: php, loops

I'm pulling an array of objects from my database and iterating through them using PHP to display a table. Each result row of the table has the option of deleting that particular record from the database. Each row is also an object, and the object type has a method that will delete itself from the database.

The problem I'm having is thinking through how to get this to work in the view. Right now if you click the delete button, it sets a POST variable to "delete" and reloads the same page wherein a listener process detects the variable and initiates the delete via a hidden input that contains the records database id.

This is all well and good, but these are all objects. Shouldn't each object be able to access it's own methods? It seems the only barrier to this is the interplay between PHP script and HTML forms. My code is below. Ideally, when the delete button is pressed, that particular instance of the object teamleader can run its method teamleader->delete_team_leader().

```
        <?php foreach($teamleaders as $teamleader) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $teamleader->first_name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $teamleader->last_name; ?></td>
        <td><img src="<?php echo '../img/' . $teamleader->photo;?>" alt="" class="img-fluid tiny-tl-img"></td>
        <td><?php echo nl2br(substr($teamleader->bio, 0, 100));?>...</td>
        <td><?php echo $teamleader->url_name;?></td>
        <form action="index.php?a=edittl" method="post">
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $teamleader->id?>">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="edit" value="Edit">
            </td>
        </form>
        <form action="index.php" method="post">
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $teamleader->id?>" name="id">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="delete" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this team leader?')">
            </td>
        </form>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the best solution I think you can use ajax/jQuery for editing or deleting action.
You don't need to use many forms as now.

The code in front-end like this:

```
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
...
<?php foreach($teamleaders as $teamleader) { ?>
    ...
    <td><?php echo $teamleader->url_name;?></td>        
    <td>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-edit" name="edit" value="Edit" data-teamleaderid="<?php echo $teamleader->id?>">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-delete" name="delete" value="Delete" data-teamleaderid="<?php echo $teamleader->id?>">
    </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

And the code with using ajax/jQuery is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.btn-delete').on('click',function(){
      var _this = $(this);
      var _teamleaderid = $(this).data('teamleaderid');

      if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this team leader?')) return false;
      $.ajax(
          url:'delete.php',
          type:'post',
          data: {
              teamleaderid: _teamleaderid
          },
          dataType:'json',
          success:function(data) {
             if (data.return) {
                 $(_this).parent().parent().remove();/*Remove the current row in table html*/
                 alert('This teamleader has been deleted');
             }
          }
      );
   });
});
```

The delete.php code in backend is:

```
<?php 
... #connect database
$teamleader_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'teamleader');
$check_delete = $dbconn->query("DELETE from teamleader_table WHERE id={$teamleader_id}");
print json_encode('return'=>$check_delete);
die();
?>
```

Comment: This is the approach I went with. I used jquery to pass in the objects id.val() field, retrieve the db object, then ran its .delete() method. On success, i used jquery to remove the row then re-number the remainders.